# Flutter - different between the real value and the displayed value

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications

I am facing very strange problem.
I want to implement the option to remove rows from DataTable, and therefore I implemented the following method:

```
onRemoveRow() {
    setState(
      () {
        lastRowIndex -= selectedGeneLists.length;
        geneLists.removeWhere((element) => selectedGeneLists.contains(element));
        for (int i = 0; i < geneLists.length; i++) {
          GenesListObjIndexed genesListObjIndexed = geneLists[i];
          genesListObjIndexed.index = i;
        }
        selectedGeneLists = [];
      },
    );
  }
```

This function should modify the list that store the table's data, and the expectation is that when I delete the items from the list the items will be deleted from the table.

But you can see here the following problem (the selected line isn't been removed):
[image]

The strange this is when I debug and check the value of the list it's look great and as expected, so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the key property to uniquely identify each row and delete the row with the key value.